# Depth First Search and Breadth First Search in C++

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I am trying to learn DFS and BFS. However, I just want to make sure that I am not doing anything wrong. Would you please determine if the BFS and DFS functions are correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
private:
    int num_of_vertices;
    vector<int> *Adj;
public:
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int from, int to);
    void BFS(int Start);
    void DFS(int Start);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->num_of_vertices = V;
    Adj = new vector<int>[V];
}
void Graph::addEdge(int from, int to)
{
    Adj[from].push_back(to);
}

void Graph::BFS(int Start)
{
    bool* visited = new bool[this->num_of_vertices]();
    queue<int> queue;
    queue.push(Start);
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    cout << "BFS: ";
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        Start = queue.front();  
        cout << Start << " ";
        visited[Start] = true;
        queue.pop();
        for (i = Adj[Start].begin(); i != Adj[Start].end(); i++)
        {
            if (!visited[*i])
                queue.push(*i);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Graph::DFS(int Start)
{
    bool* visited = new bool[this->num_of_vertices]();
    stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(Start);
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    cout << "DFS: ";
    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        int top = stack.top();
        cout << top << " ";
        stack.pop();
        visited[top] = true;
        for(i = Adj[top].begin(); i != Adj[top].end(); i++)
        {
            if (!visited[*i])
                stack.push(*i);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of the `BFS` and `DFS` algorithms themselves seems correct(but it is a good practice to write unit-tests to make sure that it works as intended, so you should do it). However, your code in general is not correct. It definitely leaks memory:

1. In the constructor, `Adj` is allocated: `Adj = new vector<int>[V];`. However, it is never deleted. You can do it in a destructor.
2. The same is true for the `visited` array(you should delete it at the end of the `DFS` and `BFS` member-functions).

Actually, there is a much easier way to deal with this issue: do not use pointers and dynamic memory allocation. I do not see any point in `visited` being allocated dynamically. Using an `std::vector` is much better(`std::vector<bool> visited(num_of_vertices)`). The same holds true for the `Adj` member-variable.

One more thing: you should try to keep the scope of variables as narrow as possible. There is no need to declare the `vector<int>::iterator i` at the beginning of the function. You can do it just inside the for loop where it is used.

The last thing: `using namespace std;` is a bad practice. It pollutes the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am aware about the memory leaks. I wrote them in a short time and I guess I forgot to write the destructor. The reason that `Adj` and `visited` arrays are dynamically allocated is because that they are dependent on the number of vertices of the graph, `V`. Thus, you cannot know the size of those arrays beforehand, so they have to be dynamically created in my opinion. Furthermore, `std::vector` also allocates memory dynamically, as the size of it grows and not created statically.

Comment: @Robomatt Yes, `std::vector` does allocate the memory dynamically. But if you use it, you don't need to care about it. So why not let it handle all allocations/deallocations issues for you?

Comment: Ok I see your point and I agree. Instead of declaring it `vector<int> *Adj;`, it is better to declare `vector< vector<int> > Adj;` and resize the vector according to the number of vertices in the graph. Am I correct?

Comment: @Robomatt Yes, exactly.